# Creating HTTP client using C++ REST SDK

Tags: c++, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm new to C++ and recently trying out the [C++ REST SDK](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/index.html): but I can't seem to create the http_client object following the tutorial from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial). I'm completely stuck right now :/

I'm using Linux Mint and the latest version of Eclipse. When I hover over the object `http_client client(U("http://www.bing.com/"))` it says:

> Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: http_client(const web::http::client::http_client &)'.

I've tried with just the string only, `http_client client("http://www.bing.com/")` and same result. I've looked through the [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1client_1_1http__client.html#a974eafd2209c47f17906aa2fa3ad2c44) and it just says to provide a string. I've searched through different tutorials and posts and it either uses just the string "http://..." or with the macro U, `U("http://www.bing.com/")`.

I've also looked at the section "What is utility::string_t and the 'U' macro?" at [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/FAQ#what-is-utilitystring_t-and-the-u-macro), but I'm not sure what to make of it other than that using the U is probably needed to create the correct type of string literal depending on the OS you're using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>

using namespace utility;                    // Common utilities like string conversions
using namespace web;                        // Common features like URIs.
using namespace web::http;                  // Common HTTP functionality
using namespace web::http::client;          // HTTP client features
using namespace concurrency::streams;       // Asynchronous streams

int main()
{
    auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();

    // Open stream to output file.
    pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("results.html")).then([=](ostream outFile)
    {
        *fileStream = outFile;
        
        http_client client(U("http://www.bing.com/"));
    });
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like Eclipse does not know the class and just defaults to the copy constructor. Have you actually tried to compile it? Have you added the directory where you installed the C++ REST SDK to the Eclipse/compiler include path?

Comment: These are the things I've changed in the project's Properties. In C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Includes > Include Paths (-l) > added the following directories which contains the header files: "/usr/include/cpprest", "/usr/include/pplx"

Comment: Then in the same window at GCC C++ Linker > Libraries > Libraries (-l) > added the following: cpprest, crypto, boost_system. Also right below Libraries (-l), I added the following to Library search path (-L): /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

Comment: Have you actually tried to compile it? What errors do you get then?

Comment: Sorry for the wording, I meant those are my current settings that were used to build/compile the project that gave the errors.

Comment: I also tried running it on a text editor using: `g++ -g httpClient_c++RestSDK.cpp -o httpClient_c++RestSDK -I /usr/include/cpprest -I /usr/include/pplx -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

It didn't get to the http_client object and gave this error: `httpClient_c++RestSDK.cpp:15:81: error: conversion from ‘pplx::details::_ContinuationTypeTraits<main(int, char**)::<lambda(Concurrency::streams::ostream)>, Concurrency::streams::basic_ostream<unsigned char> >::_TaskOfType {aka pplx::task<web::http::http_response>}’ to non-scalar type ‘pplx::task<void>’ requested`

Comment: `pplx::task<void>` is probably not the type that `fstream::open_ostream()` returns. Try replacing it with `auto requestTask = fstrream::open_ostream(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but ultimately I've decided to use another library (POCO). I did try the `auto requestTask = fstrream::open_ostream(...)` and it seemed to have work, but it then gave similar errors from Eclipse for the `http_client client(U("http://www.bing.com/"));`.